# HtmlAgility - extract and replace plain text part (outside any tags) from HTML

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, httphandler

I use `HtmlAgility` pack and I want to extract and replace each plain text part (not inside tags) from HTML.

```
<html><body>bla bla 1<br />bla bla 2<br />bla bla 3<img src="img.jpg" /></body></html>
```

The output should be a list including `bla bla 1`; `bla bla 2`; `bla bla 3`;

`node.InnerText` does not apply here.

Comment: could you give a real world example with non blabla html? because there are a million ways to do it, on way for example is `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").InnerText` but i am sure thats not what you want, one more way is `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()")`

Comment: Edited one more time by adding a extra tag (can be image, ...) just after the last "bla bla", making my answer not working

Answer (score 0):

I used :

```
// loop over innerhtml and process
var thenode = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "body").FirstOrDefault();
if (thenode != null)
{
    // InnerHtml replaces <br /> with <br>
    String[] strings = thenode.InnerHtml.Split(new string[] { "<br>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (String str in strings)
    {
        String lstr = str.Trim();
        if (lstr != String.Empty && !lstr.StartsWith("<"))
        {
            // do processing
            String loutput = Processing(lstr);
            thenode.InnerHtml = thenode.InnerHtml.Replace(lstr, loutput);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to replace all text nodes *within* `<body>` tag with some new text :

```
//select all text nodes that is "direct child of <body>" and "not empty"
var textNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body/text()[normalize-space()]");
foreach (HtmlNode textNode in textNodes)
{
    textNode.ParentNode
            //replace each text node with "new text" for the sake of demo
            .ReplaceChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode("new text")
                          , textNode
            );
}
```

Side note: I didn't see the text nodes as *outside any tag*, because they are *inside* the `<body>` tag. I see them as *direct child* of `<body>` tag.